# Best Way to Implement a Versioning System for User Edited Content

Tags: mysql, database-design, architecture, data-modeling

I have a requirement to let users edit each others entries.  So in case of bad entries, I need to be able to go back to an earlier version.

What is the best way to implement this in the data layer?  Should I have like a triage table?  And once the admin approves the edit, the triage version gets copied and put into the main entries table?

How would you guys do this?

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer may work for you.

[Rolling Your Own Plaintext Wiki (Wiki inside a DB)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613038/rolling-your-own-plaintext-wiki-wiki-inside-a-db/613165#613165)

Answer (score 1):

I know you're thinking in terms of a database, but you may want to look in to using Mercurial or Git as the back-end to your application.  It won't work like a database, but you'll have full version control.